# Signing a transaction with uport can't approve as the selected account can't change.How can i change in uport selected account?

Tags: ethereumjs, uport

I am developing a dapp with uport verifications but when I go for saving information into ropsten network, a uport signing transaction appears on my screen and I can't approved the transaction.

I have no balance on selected account on uport. but I have balance on others account on ropsten network. how can I change the selected account on mu uport mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. This is because you should have an account created by uport app and this does not come along with the app installation. I would suggest you to move from ropsten to rinkeby test network as uport have officially switched to rinkeby testnet. Then follow this example (https://developer.uport.me/credentials/transactions). Once you do this, this is going to create a rinkeby account for you which you can see in the profile section. Load enough rinkeby test ethers from faucet or metamask and then you will be able to sign all transactions on rinkeby testnet.